# how to implement listbox?

Tags: c++, win32gui

I'm trying to develop a winform in vc++

How to implement a listbox with 3 columns(file name, created by, size) in win32 application and add filename(when i click on it it opens the file) and created by values to it?

Comment: ¤ For a multiple column list consider a **[ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774737%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)** instead of a "list box". Note that you should `INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX` before using it. I do not know why Microsoft chose such a controversial name. Cheers & hth.,